# How to add a dropdown menu to my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frameworks

I'm building a react app using facebook's:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

along w SASS: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

I'm at a point now where I need to add a dropdown menu to the header. Similar to the header icons on StackOverflow in the top right that open and close on click.

I know this sounds like a dumb question but what is the right way to do this? Do I need to add a UI Framework like a bootstrap for something like this? I have no need for all the bootstrap theming etc...

Thank you - and please be kind to the question given I'm a solo developer and could really use some help building a solid foundation on my app.

Thanks

Comment: A bit of a broad question, but start with `<select><option>1</option></select>`. I'm sure that's not what you want though.

Comment: I'm not looking to great an input field, but rather a list dropdown like when you click the MAIL or TROPHY icon in the Stackoverflow header. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this easily with just React:

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="nav">
      <Link />
      <Link />
      <Link />
    </div>;
  }
}

class Link extends React.Component {
 state = {
   open: false
  }
  handleClick = () => {
   this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  }
  render () {
   const { open } = this.state;
   return (
     <div className="link">
       <span onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</span>
        <div className={`menu ${open ? 'open' : ''}`}>
          <ul>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.link {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px; // same as your nav height
  left: 0;
  background: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.menu.open {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `react-select` like this :

```
var Select = require('react-select');

var options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

function logChange(val) {
  console.log("Selected: " + JSON.stringify(val));
}

<Select
  name="form-field-name"
  value="one"
  options={options}
  onChange={logChange}
/>
```

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

also this library :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown

Comment: Thanks but isn't react-select for INPUT fields? I'm looking to create a menu item like in the header of Stackoverflow when you click the MAIL icon...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your project is still in his infancy. And that you willing to incorporate a library to your project. So I would definitely recommend you to choose a library right now.

With React you could create your own menu without much effort. But you will also need other components for the rest of your app. And the quality of your menu (and other components) will most likely be greater if you choose a library used by many (rather than your own). For "quality" I mean: UX design, HTML standards, API reusability, number of defects, etc.

If you think your app will be small and won't need an entire UI Framework, you might want to search for an isolated component for menu. Here is a list of navigation components (including the number of github stars of each project):
https://devarchy.com/react/topic/navigation

But in most cases I would choose an entire UI Framework instead: https://devarchy.com/react/topic/ui-framework

And here are some demos of the menu/nav/app-bar of some popular UI Frameworks:

- https://ant.design/components/menu/
- https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs-dropdown
- http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

Answer (score 0):

**Custom dropdown**

Dropdown.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { mdiMenuDown } from "@mdi/js";
import Icon from "@mdi/react";
export default function DropDown({ placeholder, content }) {
const [active, setactive] = useState(0);
const [value, setvalue] = useState(0);
return (
<div className={active ? "dropdown_wrapper active" : "dropdown_wrapper"}>
  <span
    onClick={() => {
      setactive(active ? 0 : 1);
    }}
  >
    {value ? value : placeholder} <Icon path={mdiMenuDown} />
  </span>
  <div className="drop_down">
    <ul>
      {content &&
        content.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <li
              onClick={() => {
                setvalue(item);
                setactive(0);
              }}
              key={key}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
);}
```

dropdown.css

```
.dropdown_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown_wrapper span {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #a8aaac;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  color: #3d3e3f;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 26px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.dropdown_wrapper span svg {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  fill: #fbb800;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
.dropdown_wrapper.active span svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
.dropdown_wrapper .drop_down {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #a8aaac;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
.dropdown_wrapper.active .drop_down {
  height: fit-content;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
.dropdown_wrapper .drop_down ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown_wrapper .drop_down ul li {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  color: #3d3e3f;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.dropdown_wrapper .drop_down ul li:hover {
  color: #faab1e;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
```

parent.js

```
<DropDown placeholder="select a type" content={["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner", "Snacks"]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

// Import your page components
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Services from "./pages/Services";
import Industries from "./pages/Industries";
import Insights from "./pages/Insights";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Careers from "./pages/Careers";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";

// Define your main App component
function App() {
  return (
    // Use the <Routes> component to set up routing in your app
    <Routes>
      {/* Define routes for different paths */}
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
      <Route path="/industries" element={<Industries />} />
      <Route path="/insights" element={<Insights />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/careers" element={<Careers />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

// Export the App component as the default export
export default App;
```

Nav.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "./logo.jpg";

// Functional component for the navigation bar
function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav>
            {/* Logo section */}
            <div className="logo">
                {/* Link to the home page */}
                <Link to="/" className="list">
                    <img src={logo} alt="Logo" width="150" height="107.35" />
                </Link>
            </div>

            {/* List of navigation links */}
            <ul>
                {/* Link to Services page */}
                <Link to="/services" className="list">
                    Services
                </Link>

                {/* Link to Industries page */}
                <Link to="/industries" className="list">
                    Industries
                </Link>

                {/* Link to Insights page */}
                <Link to="/insights" className="list">
                    Insights
                </Link>

                {/* Link to About page */}
                <Link to="/about" className="list">
                    About
                </Link>

                {/* Link to Careers page */}
                <Link to="/careers" className="list">
                    Careers
                </Link>

                {/* Link to Contact page */}
                <Link to="/contact" className="list">
                    Contact
                </Link>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

About.js

```
import React from "react"
import Navbar from "../Navbar"


function About(){
    return(
        <div>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <div className="content"><h1 style={{color: "#d094ea"}}>About</h1></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

app.css

```
html,body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%; 
}

.container {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;


}



nav {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color:black;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;

}

.logo {

  padding-top: 10px;

}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0 0px 180px;
  
}



.list {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(188, 206, 251);
  padding: 20px 30px 30px 20px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.list:hover {
  color: rgb(208, 148, 234);
}

.list.active {
  background-color: #555;
}

.page-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.content {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 250px;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

app.css

```
html,body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%; 
}

.container {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;


}



nav {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color:black;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;

}

.logo {

  padding-top: 10px;

}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0 0px 180px;
  
}



.list {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 20px 30px 30px 20px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.list:hover {
  color: rgb(69, 150, 170);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.list.active {
  background-color: #555;
}

.page-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.content {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 250px;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}


input {

  height: 45px;

  padding: 10px 15px;

  margin-bottom: 15px;

}

button {

  width: 200px;

  outline: none;

  border: none;

  padding: 15px;

  cursor: pointer;

  font-size: 16px;

}

.login__container,

.signup__container,

.verify,

.dashboard {

  width: 100%;

  min-height: 100vh;

  padding: 50px 70px;

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;

  align-items: center;

  justify-content: center;

}

.login__form,

.verify__form,

.signup__form {

  width: 100%;

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;

}

.loginBtn,

.signupBtn,

.codeBtn {

  background-color: green;

  color: #fff;

  margin-bottom: 15px;

}

.signOutBtn {

  background-color: #c21010;

  color: #fff;

}

.link {

  cursor: pointer;

  color: rgb(39, 147, 39);

}

.code {

  width: 50%;

  text-align: center;

}

.verify__form {

  align-items: center;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .login__container,

  .signup__container,

  .verify {

      padding: 30px;

  }

}
```

login

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


const Login = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const navigate = useNavigate();


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log({ email, password });

        setPassword("");

        setEmail("");

    };


    const gotoSignUpPage = () => navigate("/Signup");


    return (

        <div className='login__container'>

            <h2>Login </h2>

            <form className='login__form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>

                <input

                    type='text'

                    id='email'

                    name='email'

                    value={email}

                    required

                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}

                />

                <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>

                <input

                    type='password'

                    name='password'

                    id='password'

                    minLength={8}

                    required

                    value={password}

                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}

                />

                <button className='loginBtn'>SIGN IN</button>

                <p>

                    Don't have an account?{" "}

                    <button className='link' onClick={gotoSignUpPage}>

                        Sign up

                    </button>

                </p>

            </form>

        </div>

    );

};


export default Login;
```

signup

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


const Signup = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

    const [tel, setTel] = useState("");

    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const navigate = useNavigate();


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log({ email, username, tel, password });

        setEmail("");

        setTel("");

        setUsername("");

        setPassword("");

    };

    const gotoLoginPage = () => navigate("/login");


    return (

        <div className='signup__container'>

            <h2>Sign up </h2>

            <form className='signup__form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                <label htmlFor='email'>Email Address</label>

                <input

                    type='email'

                    name='email'

                    id='email'

                    value={email}

                    required

                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}

                />

                <label htmlFor='username'>Username</label>

                <input

                    type='text'

                    id='username'

                    name='username'

                    value={username}

                    required

                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}

                />

                <label htmlFor='tel'>Phone Number</label>

                <input

                    type='tel'

                    name='tel'

                    id='tel'

                    value={tel}

                    required

                    onChange={(e) => setTel(e.target.value)}

                />

                <label htmlFor='tel'>Password</label>

                <input

                    type='password'

                    name='password'

                    id='password'

                    minLength={8}

                    required

                    value={password}

                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}

                />

                <button className='signupBtn'>SIGN UP</button>

                <p>

                    Already have an account?{" "}

                    <button className='link' onClick={gotoLoginPage}>

                        Login

                    </button>

                </p>

            </form>

        </div>

    );

};


export default Signup;
```

login logic

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
export default function Form({name,mail,password,sname,smail,spassword,list}){
    const navigate=useNavigate()//object for usenavigate
    const log=()=>{
        let n=name
        n= n.toLowerCase()
        var flag=0
        var set=0
        //condition to check name
        if (name.length < 3 || name.length >= 20 || !(/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(name))) {
            flag-=1
        } 
        else {
            flag+=1
        }
        //condition to check mail
        if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-z]+[a-z]+[a-z]+)$/.test(mail))) {
            flag-=1
        } else {
            flag+=1
        }
        //condition  to  check password
        var lower = 0;
        var upper = 0;
        var special = 0;
        var number = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
            if (password[i] >= "A" && password[i] <= "Z") {
                upper += 1;
            } else if (password[i] >= "a" && password[i] <= "z") {
                lower += 1;
            } else if (password[i] >= "0" && password[i] <= "9") {
                number += 1;
            } else {
                special += 1;
            }
        }
        if (password.length < 8 || (upper < 1 || lower < 1) || (number < 1 || special < 1)) {
            flag-=1
        } else {
            flag += 1; 
        }
    
        if (flag === 3) 
        {
            //checks if the entered value is there in the list
           for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                if(n===list[i].name.toLowerCase() & password===list[i].password){
                        set=1
                    }
               }
            if(set===1){
                //specifies the path
                navigate('/Mpage') 
            }
            else{
                alert("Invalid uername or password")
            }
                
        }
        else if(flag>=0 & flag<3){
            alert("please fill all the fields")
        }
        else{
            alert("entered details are not correct")
        }
            
           
         
       
    }
   
    return(
        <div className="forms">
        <form className="input">
            <input type="text" value={name}  placeholder="enter username" onInput={(e)=>{sname(e.target.value)}} required></input>
            <input type="text" value={mail} placeholder="enter your email" onInput={(e)=>{smail(e.target.value)}} required></input>
            <input type="password" value={password} placeholder="enter your password" onInput={(e)=>{spassword(e.target.value)}} required></input>
            <button className="button" onClick={log}>Login</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).